# JsonPatchDocument Not getting displayed properly in Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web API Swagger

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have my API documented and versioned previously using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer`.

Everything was fine but all of a sudden today I noticed that `JsonPatchDocument` Not getting displayed properly in my swagger. I couldn't figure out what's the root cause. But I suspect some `Nuget Package` Upgrade?

Previously I remember the `JsonPatchDocument` in my swagger as something similar below:

```cs
{
   "Operations": [
     {
       "value": {},
       "path": "string",
       "op": "string",
       "from": "string"
     }
   ]
}
```

But now it shows something else,

```cs
{
  "ContractResolver": {}
}
```

Please assist on what I'm missing

Comment: Hey man, were you ever able to figure out what was the issue and fix it?

Comment: nope. will post the answer once I resolve this.

Comment: Check that the AddNewtonsoftJson() extension method exists in the Startup.cs (Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are added the AddNewtonsoftJson in program.cs after install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsofJson

should be like this :
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();